# @Autowired fields are getting null when @PostConstruct method is called

Tags: java, spring

As stated in question in ServiceB my `@Autowired` fields are getting null

```
@Service
@Component
@ComponentScan({ "com.package" })
@Transactional
public class ServiceA {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceB serviceB

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Calling method in serviceB
        serviceB.getService();
    }

}

@Service
@Component
@ComponentScan({ "com.package" })
@Transactional
public class ServiceB {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceC serviceC // Getting null

    @Autowired
    private ServiceD serviceD // Getting null

    @Autowired
    private ServiceE serviceE // Getting null

    // This method is called from the PostConstruct
    getService() {
        serviceC.getAnotherService(); // Here getting NPE as serviceC is getting null
    }

}

@Service
@Component
@ComponentScan({ "com.package" })
@Transactional
public class ServiceC {

     getAnotherService() {
         // This method is being not called
     }
}
```

Is there any way to load all the `@Autowired` components before `@PostConstruct`

Comment: Use constructor injection. Then the object cannot be created without having the dependencies initialized.

Comment: Okay, Will change it to constructor injection

Comment: Note : `@Service` and `@Component` together are not required , either one of the would do. `@ComponentScan` to be moved to a `@Configuration` class and not required in every class

Comment: Okay, Will change accordingly